# Single sign on Liferay 5.2.3

Tags: liferay, single-sign-on

We are having several communities running on our single liferay(5.x) installation. 
The user base for all these communities is same.
Now we want that if a user is logged in into one community and he click on a link for other community , he should be automatically signed in that community.

For example if there are 2 domains: domain1.com and domain2.com. Both these domains would be communities in liferay. If I am logged in on domain1.com and I am trying to click a private page of domain2.com then I want I should not get log - in screen in domain2.com. I should get automatically signed in domain2 because I am signed in domain1.com

What are the ways of doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

Once logged in you should be signed in to all communities that you have access to. One way I would do this is:

1. Sign in to community 1
2. Navigate to the Control Panel
3. Go the "Communities" option under the "Portal" section
4. Click on Public or Private pages of the Community I want to view

As far as I'm aware access to communities is single sign-on providing you have the required permissions for that Community.